# Boot, How to run my service **after** Network Manager?

Tags: boot, networking, network-manager, services

I have made a service - which changes settings of network interfaces -.

I want to start it at boot.

**Issue**: even if I set it 99 *priority*, it works only a few seconds. It seems its interfaces config is then *broken*.

**My question** is **supposing it is a matter of interfaces update a-f-t-e-r my service has started, how can I start it after NetworkManager ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are running a system with systemd, check out this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126146/130303
- If you are running an "older" ubuntu version (14.04), check here: https://superuser.com/a/248671